# How to mount a vue component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I normally import my components like so:

```
Vue.component('comments', require('./components/Comments.vue'));
```

But I wish to manually mount the .vue file depending on a condition. The docs state:

```
var MyComponent = Vue.extend({
    template: '<div>Hello!</div>'
})

var component = new MyComponent().$mount()
document.getElementById('app').appendChild(component.$el)
```

But how do I mount a component in a separate vue file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't manually mount components, it's generally only useful in testing and certain circumstances where you can only mount after an element becomes available (i.e. when integrating with legacy code).

In the case of `single file components`, your base component is already mounted so `Vue` will handle this for you. In your case you should use `v-if` which only mounts the component when the condition is met; you don't have to do it manually.

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5p3nq001/

Comment: Thanks - I've considered v-if but the comments component that needs mounting is no where near the button that mounts it in the markup - so the comments component can not be a child of the button component to use v-if. Any ideas a way round this?

Comment: @panthro In that case you can simply `emit` the event back to the parent, which updates the relevant flag, here's the [updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eh58yLLn/) or if it's much further away you can use an `event bus`.

Comment: The parent would be my root app. If I have 20 or so of these buttons on the page (think of a page of cards), how will it know which comments section to open?

Comment: That's a bit trickier depending on your setup. If you have a separate comments sections for each card, which you cannot display on the card component itself, but need the parent to know which card has been chosen then you can pass an `id` or `index` as a prop and emit it back to the parent, you can then have an array of comments with their own show flag, [here's a JSFiddle using indexes](https://jsfiddle.net/j381f3fr/) but depending on your data this may need a bit of rearranging.

Comment: Thanks for the advice and the great example. Much appreciated.